# Hive: How to join two tables such that all entries from two columns are in the final able?

Tags: join, merge, hive, hiveql

I have two tables in Hive

```
t1:
prod | rev
-------------
A |   1
A |   2
B |   1
B |   2
D |   1


t2:
prod | rev
-------------
A |   1
A |   2
B |   1
B |   2
C |   1
C |   2
```

I want to join them together such that all produdcts (prod) and revisions (rev) are in the final table such as.

```
t3:
prod | rev
-------------
A |   1
A |   2
B |   1
B |   2
C |   1
C |   2
D |   1
```

I have tried but just am not familar with HQL enough to understand how to properly do it.

I believe that perhaps a LEFT JOIN then UNION ALL then RIGHT JOIN would work. And to also use a WHERE statement after UNION ALL to remove duplicates, but I can't write a working query. Would love any help on this.

Comment: you can find many queries on SO related to this. you need to search a bit

Comment: A simple `UNION` should suffice. You don't want `UNION ALL` as that will give you duplicates.

Comment: "LEFT JOIN then UNION ALL then RIGHT JOIN" - this is what FULL JOIN does, you need to remove duplicates after it. But as @Nick says, simple UNION will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `union` should do it.

```
select * from t1
union
select * from t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `UNION DISTINCT` which can eliminate duplicates in the output

```
select * from t1
UNION DISTINCT
select * from t2
```